# How to replace tag with some value in XML using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a predefine XML template with some tags that need to be replaced. The tag values come dynamically from the front-end.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>AUTHOR1</author>
      <title>TITLE1</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>AUTHOR2</author>
      <title>TITLE2</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
 </catalog>
```

In above example I need to replace `TITLE1`, `TITLE2`, `AUTHOR1`, `AUTHOR2` with the actual value dynamically.

What is the best way to do this? I am using Nokogiri in some Ruby code but have had no luck.

Comment: What if TITLE1 exists in the description?

Comment: These are the Predefine tag so they are unique.

Comment: We need to see a summarized code example demonstrating the problem. It's easier for us and better for you if we correct your code than if we write something totally unrelated that doesn't fit your code. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Agreed. I appreciate the suggestion and It is new learning experience for me. Thanks once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is you need to search the XML for the `<book>` tags. For each book found, retrieve the block of values that apply to it. Find the `<author>` tag and replace its text. Find the `<title>` tag, and replace its text also. Then go to the next book.

However, in your example, writing code to do that is overkill when a simple `gsub` will do it in one pass:

```
xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>AUTHOR1</author>
      <title>TITLE1</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>AUTHOR2</author>
      <title>TITLE2</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
 </catalog>
'

values = {
  'TITLE1' => 'Moby Dick',
  'AUTHOR1' => 'Herman Melville',
  'TITLE2' => 'Tom Sawyer',
  'AUTHOR2' => 'Mark Twain',
}

puts xml.gsub(Regexp.union(values.keys), values)
# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <catalog>
# >>    <book id="bk101">
# >>       <author>Herman Melville</author>
# >>       <title>Moby Dick</title>
# >>       <genre>Computer</genre>
# >>       <price>44.95</price>
# >>       <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
# >>       <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
# >>       with XML.</description>
# >>    </book>
# >>    <book id="bk102">
# >>       <author>Mark Twain</author>
# >>       <title>Tom Sawyer</title>
# >>       <genre>Fantasy</genre>
# >>       <price>5.95</price>
# >>       <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
# >>       <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
# >>       an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
# >>       of the world.</description>
# >>    </book>
# >>  </catalog>
```

This use of [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-gsub) isn't used often, but I've used it many times when substituting values into templates. Using tags/keys that are guaranteed to be unique in the document are essential, so I often flag them using leading and trailing double underscores. In other words `__TITLE1__`, `__AUTHOR1__`, etc.

Doing this you can easily replace the content of the other fields, such as `<genre>`, `<price>`, etc.

Name the variables in the form the same as the keys/tags, and the task becomes even easier because you should receive a hash of field-names and field-values, which becomes the source for your hash used in the `gsub`.

Be sure to verify/sanitize the values before substituting. Users mistype and malicious ones can deliberately enter data in an attempt to break your code, or worse, whatever the XML is fed into.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just need to know one more thing the template I am using is not a string. It is placed in a file and from there I am reading XML :-                                                                          Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse(File.open(file_path))